# Can we disable calendar event notification popup when our application is opened in iPad?

Tags: ios, calendar, notifications

I am working on an application in which we have a requirement to block calendar event alert or any other application alert when our application is opened. User should not see any popup from outside application when user is on any screen in our application. Please let us know if this can be done.

Comment: i don't think that this is possible with a normal device. perhaps with jailbreaked devices.

Comment: It would be terrible if 3rd party apps could disable notifications and alerts. I don't want to miss a meeting just because I happen to be using some app.

Answer (score 1):

No, You can't do that.

From a usability perspective, it would also be problematic. Your user might actually be interested in events from other apps, while using yours.